# Calabash is no longer under active development by Xamarin

Tags: ruby, xamarin, calabash

I just goto know that from xamarin website saying "Please note that Calabash is no longer under active development." what does it mean now, any idea on who will be taking calabash further? What is the roadmap for calabash? any alternatives from Xamarin?

Comment: You can write tests in C# using Xamarin UITest